# Can I switch the database per one connection on SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I use multiple databases for my application.
I don't want to connect multiple connections to db per request.
How can I switch database per one connection on SQLAlchemy?
I use session.bind for db connection.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "switch database per one connection". Are you trying to connect to multiple databases while running one application (python script)?

Comment: That's right. That's same host but different database name.

Comment: Have you tried closing your current session? And opening a new session?

Comment: No. Because I need to switch database name in multiple time thorough per connection.